# How can I center a label using Tkinter's grid method in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm trying to center a Label in Tkinter. I am using the grid() method to show my widgets.
In the code below I created a frame and put the label in that frame.
The sticky method doesn't seem to work for some reason.
I have tried sticky='WE' but the label is still stuck to the left side of the frame.

'''

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

mw=Tk()
mw.title('Window')
mw_width, mw_height = 300, 200
mw.minsize(mw_width,mw_height)

frame1=Frame(mw)
frame1.grid(row=0,column=0)

main_label=ttk.Label(frame1,text='My label')
main_label.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='WE')

mw.mainloop()
```

'''

Comment: From the documentation https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_grid.htm "By default, with sticky='', widget is centered in its cell." There is no WE, there are compass directions for sticky i.e. (N, E, S, W, NE, NW, SE and SW)

Answer (score 2):

`grid` by default will center a widget in the space allocated to it. The problem is that you've not configured the column to grow to fill the window. Also by default, a row or column will be just large enough to fit the widgets in it.

To do that, you need to give column 0 a non-zero weight:

```
mw.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use the grid() method for your layout? pack() would automatically center it.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

mw=Tk()
mw.title('Window')
mw_width, mw_height = 300, 200
mw.minsize(mw_width,mw_height)

frame1=Frame(mw)
frame1.pack()

main_label=ttk.Label(frame1,text='My label', justify="center")
main_label.pack()

mw.mainloop()
```

You could also use place().

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

mw = Tk()
mw.title('Window')
mw_width, mw_height = 300, 200
mw.minsize(mw_width, mw_height)

frame1 = Frame(mw)
frame1.place(width=mw_width, height=mw_height)

main_label = ttk.Label(frame1, text='My label', justify="center")
main_label.place(relx=.5, rely=0, anchor="n")

mw.mainloop()
```